# Undefined reference error in C++/Qt

Tags: c++, qt, include, static-libraries, tesseract

I am trying to include Tesseract OCR library into my Qt project. I have done everything according to instructions, but it doesn't work.

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR =
            new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
```

Error - **undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()'**

As I think, it's linking problem, but I'm not sure. Take a look of .pro file (only necessary code):

```
unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/ -llibtesseract302

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/tesseract
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/tesseract

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/libtesseract302.lib

unix|win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/ -lliblept168

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/leptonica
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/include/leptonica

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../Tesseract-OCR/lib/liblept168.lib

DEFINES += _tagBLOB_DEFINED
DEFINES += USE_STD_NAMESPACE
DEFINES += WINDLLNAME=\\\"lib$$TARGET.dll\\\"
DEFINES += VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
DEFINES -= UNICODE

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/api
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/ccmain
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/ccutil
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/ccstruct
INCLUDEPATH += C:/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract-ocr/include

LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/liblept168-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/giflib416-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/libjpeg8c-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/libtiff394-static-mtdll.lib
LIBS += C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/zlib125-static-mtdll.lib
```

Every function of TessBaseAPI has the same error.

Comment: What OS are you trying to build on? For *nix you shouldn't be putting the 'lib' prefix on for library names.

Comment: I'd make sure there're no "everything-in-a-namespace" defines in the .pro for the lib (if there are some, it may be the library was compiled with non-namespaced names, and thus, while include files work, the symbols do not match)

Comment: Libraries are linked, but there is an error APPCRASH, connected with libtesseract-3.dll. If I add more dll's to .pro file, another error occurs : Qt stops program with error -1072365566. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

First: **"undefined reference"** means liker can not find appropriate static library, so look into this direction.

According to [this](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/377), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427308/link-tesseract-libs-with-qtcreator) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tesseract-ocr/miqqBbWUDhU) Tesseract needs libtesseract.lib (.a) but also liblept.lib (.a).

I recommend to not be very fancy with your .pro file at first and just try to build and run a bare minimum (and I suspect it needs only these two libraries and *probably* some DLLs).

Also I recommend to specify libraries you want to link in .pro file like this:

```
LIBS += -L" C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/" -llept
```

or even better like this (if your libraries are copied inside your project folder)

```
LIBS += -L" $$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/Tesseract-OCR/lib/" -llept
```

but **not** like this

```
LIBS +=  C:/Tesseract-OCR/lib/liblept.lib
```