# Link tesseract libs with QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, tesseract

I'm trying to run a C++ program which is based on tesseract API and I'm using QtCreator as IDE on Ubuntu, in order to perfom page layout analysis :

```
int main(void)
{
int left, top, right, bottom;

tesseract::TessBaseAPI tessApi;
tessApi.InitForAnalysePage();

cv::Mat img = cv::imread("document.png");
tessApi.SetImage(reinterpret_cast<const uchar*>(img.data), img.size().width, img.size().height, img.channels(), img.step1());

tesseract::PageIterator *iter = tessApi.AnalyseLayout();

while (iter->Next(tesseract::RIL_BLOCK))
    iter->BoundingBox( tesseract::RIL_BLOCK, &left, &top, &right, &bottom);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But in turn I got these kind of errors confirming that tesseract and Qt aren't linked :

```
main.cpp:11: error: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::TessBaseAPI()'
main.cpp:12: error: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::InitForAnalysePage()'
main.cpp:16: error: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::SetImage(unsigned char const*, int, int, int, int)'
main.cpp:18: error: undefined reference to `tesseract::TessBaseAPI::AnalyseLayout()'
```

Here is my .pro file :

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/include/opencv \
           /usr/include/tesseract

LIBS += -L"/usr/local/opencv/lib"   -lopencv_calib3d \
                                -lopencv_contrib \
                                -lopencv_core \
                                -lopencv_features2d \
                                -lopencv_flann \
                                -lopencv_gpu \
                                -lopencv_highgui \
                                -lopencv_imgproc \
                                -lopencv_legacy \
                                -lopencv_ml \
                                -lopencv_nonfree \
                                -lopencv_objdetect \
                                -lopencv_ocl \
                                -lopencv_photo \
                                -lopencv_stitching \
                                -lopencv_superres \
                                -lopencv_video \
                                -lopencv_videostab

LIBS += -L"/usr/bin/tesseract"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have the path for the lib `-L"/usr/bin/tesseract"`, you forgot to include the lib as well. Just add it like you did for the openCV libs.

Comment: But the problem is when I try to get the libraries using this command line :    `pkg-config --cflags tesseract` I get this answer : 
    `Package tesseract was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing tesseract.pc
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
   No package tesseract found`

Comment: Then you should have a library named libtesseract.so in your /usr/lib/ or similar folder. Try to add it to the project.

Comment: Yes I found it, but I don't know how to add it to the project. Can you give me some hints ?

Comment: Try to change the line `LIBS += -L"/usr/bin/tesseract"` in your .pro file to `LIBS += -L"(path to lib folder)" -ltesseract`

Comment: No problem! Good luck :)